# Set max width 800px on Lightbox plugin

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Hello i use this lightbox plugin for one of my website and i will like when the picture open to have max width 800px, but because i'm beginner in Jquery i have no idea where i suppose to set this here :

```
/**
 * jQuery lightBox plugin
 * This jQuery plugin was inspired and based on Lightbox 2 by Lokesh Dhakar (http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)
 * and adapted to me for use like a plugin from jQuery.
 * @name jquery-lightbox-0.5.js
 * @author Leandro Vieira Pinho - http://leandrovieira.com
 * @version 0.5
 * @date April 11, 2008
 * @category jQuery plugin
 * @copyright (c) 2008 Leandro Vieira Pinho (leandrovieira.com)
 * @license CCAttribution-ShareAlike 2.5 Brazil - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/br/deed.en_US
 * @example Visit http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ for more informations about this jQuery plugin
 */
(function($){$.fn.lightBox=function(settings){settings=jQuery.extend({overlayBgColor:'#000',overlayOpacity:0.8,fixedNavigation:false,imageLoading:'css/images/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',imageBtnPrev:'css/images/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',imageBtnNext:'css/images/lightbox-btn-next.gif',imageBtnClose:'css/images/lightbox-btn-close.gif',imageBlank:'css/images/lightbox-blank.gif',containerBorderSize:10,containerResizeSpeed:400,txtImage:'Image',txtOf:'of',keyToClose:'c',keyToPrev:'p',keyToNext:'n',imageArray:[],activeImage:0},settings);var jQueryMatchedObj=this;function _initialize(){_start(this,jQueryMatchedObj);return false}function _start(objClicked,jQueryMatchedObj){$('embed, object, select').css({'visibility':'hidden'});_set_interface();settings.imageArray.length=0;settings.activeImage=0;if(jQueryMatchedObj.length==1){settings.imageArray.push(new Array(objClicked.getAttribute('href'),objClicked.getAttribute('title')))}else{for(var i=0;i<jQueryMatchedObj.length;i++){settings.imageArray.push(new Array(jQueryMatchedObj[i].getAttribute('href'),jQueryMatchedObj[i].getAttribute('title')))}}while(settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0]!=objClicked.getAttribute('href')){settings.activeImage++}_set_image_to_view()}function _set_interface(){$('body').append('<div id="jquery-overlay"></div><div id="jquery-lightbox"><div id="lightbox-container-image-box"><div id="lightbox-container-image"><img id="lightbox-image"><div style="" id="lightbox-nav"><a href="#" id="lightbox-nav-btnPrev"></a><a href="#" id="lightbox-nav-btnNext"></a></div><div id="lightbox-loading"><a href="#" id="lightbox-loading-link"><img src="'+settings.imageLoading+'"></a></div></div></div><div id="lightbox-container-image-data-box"><div id="lightbox-container-image-data"><div id="lightbox-image-details"><span id="lightbox-image-details-caption"></span><span id="lightbox-image-details-currentNumber"></span></div><div id="lightbox-secNav"><a href="#" id="lightbox-secNav-btnClose"><img src="'+settings.imageBtnClose+'"></a></div></div></div></div>');var arrPageSizes=___getPageSize();$('#jquery-overlay').css({backgroundColor:settings.overlayBgColor,opacity:settings.overlayOpacity,width:arrPageSizes[0],height:arrPageSizes[1]}).fadeIn();var arrPageScroll=___getPageScroll();$('#jquery-lightbox').css({top:arrPageScroll[1]+(arrPageSizes[3]/10),left:arrPageScroll[0]}).show();$('#jquery-overlay,#jquery-lightbox').click(function(){_finish()});$('#lightbox-loading-link,#lightbox-secNav-btnClose').click(function(){_finish();return false});$(window).resize(function(){var arrPageSizes=___getPageSize();$('#jquery-overlay').css({width:arrPageSizes[0],height:arrPageSizes[1]});var arrPageScroll=___getPageScroll();$('#jquery-lightbox').css({top:arrPageScroll[1]+(arrPageSizes[3]/10),left:arrPageScroll[0]})})}function _set_image_to_view(){$('#lightbox-loading').show();if(settings.fixedNavigation){$('#lightbox-image,#lightbox-container-image-data-box,#lightbox-image-details-currentNumber').hide()}else{$('#lightbox-image,#lightbox-nav,#lightbox-nav-btnPrev,#lightbox-nav-btnNext,#lightbox-container-image-data-box,#lightbox-image-details-currentNumber').hide()}var objImagePreloader=new Image();objImagePreloader.onload=function(){$('#lightbox-image').attr('src',settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0]);_resize_container_image_box(objImagePreloader.width,objImagePreloader.height);objImagePreloader.onload=function(){}};objImagePreloader.src=settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][0]};function _resize_container_image_box(intImageWidth,intImageHeight){var intCurrentWidth=$('#lightbox-container-image-box').width();var intCurrentHeight=$('#lightbox-container-image-box').height();var intWidth=(intImageWidth+(settings.containerBorderSize*2));var intHeight=(intImageHeight+(settings.containerBorderSize*2));var intDiffW=intCurrentWidth-intWidth;var intDiffH=intCurrentHeight-intHeight;$('#lightbox-container-image-box').animate({width:intWidth,height:intHeight},settings.containerResizeSpeed,function(){_show_image()});if((intDiffW==0)&&(intDiffH==0)){if($.browser.msie){___pause(250)}else{___pause(100)}}$('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').css({width:intImageWidth});$('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev,#lightbox-nav-btnNext').css({height:intImageHeight+(settings.containerBorderSize*2)})};function _show_image(){$('#lightbox-loading').hide();$('#lightbox-image').fadeIn(function(){_show_image_data();_set_navigation()});_preload_neighbor_images()};function _show_image_data(){$('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').slideDown('fast');$('#lightbox-image-details-caption').hide();if(settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][1]){$('#lightbox-image-details-caption').html(settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage][1]).show()}if(settings.imageArray.length>1){$('#lightbox-image-details-currentNumber').html(settings.txtImage+' '+(settings.activeImage+1)+' '+settings.txtOf+' '+settings.imageArray.length).show()}}function _set_navigation(){$('#lightbox-nav').show();$('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev,#lightbox-nav-btnNext').css({'background':'transparent url('+settings.imageBlank+') no-repeat'});if(settings.activeImage!=0){if(settings.fixedNavigation){$('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev').css({'background':'url('+settings.imageBtnPrev+') left 15% no-repeat'}).unbind().bind('click',function(){settings.activeImage=settings.activeImage-1;_set_image_to_view();return false})}else{$('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev').unbind().hover(function(){$(this).css({'background':'url('+settings.imageBtnPrev+') left 15% no-repeat'})},function(){$(this).css({'background':'transparent url('+settings.imageBlank+') no-repeat'})}).show().bind('click',function(){settings.activeImage=settings.activeImage-1;_set_image_to_view();return false})}}if(settings.activeImage!=(settings.imageArray.length-1)){if(settings.fixedNavigation){$('#lightbox-nav-btnNext').css({'background':'url('+settings.imageBtnNext+') right 15% no-repeat'}).unbind().bind('click',function(){settings.activeImage=settings.activeImage+1;_set_image_to_view();return false})}else{$('#lightbox-nav-btnNext').unbind().hover(function(){$(this).css({'background':'url('+settings.imageBtnNext+') right 15% no-repeat'})},function(){$(this).css({'background':'transparent url('+settings.imageBlank+') no-repeat'})}).show().bind('click',function(){settings.activeImage=settings.activeImage+1;_set_image_to_view();return false})}}_enable_keyboard_navigation()}function _enable_keyboard_navigation(){$(document).keydown(function(objEvent){_keyboard_action(objEvent)})}function _disable_keyboard_navigation(){$(document).unbind()}function _keyboard_action(objEvent){if(objEvent==null){keycode=event.keyCode;escapeKey=27}else{keycode=objEvent.keyCode;escapeKey=objEvent.DOM_VK_ESCAPE}key=String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();if((key==settings.keyToClose)||(key=='x')||(keycode==escapeKey)){_finish()}if((key==settings.keyToPrev)||(keycode==37)){if(settings.activeImage!=0){settings.activeImage=settings.activeImage-1;_set_image_to_view();_disable_keyboard_navigation()}}if((key==settings.keyToNext)||(keycode==39)){if(settings.activeImage!=(settings.imageArray.length-1)){settings.activeImage=settings.activeImage+1;_set_image_to_view();_disable_keyboard_navigation()}}}function _preload_neighbor_images(){if((settings.imageArray.length-1)>settings.activeImage){objNext=new Image();objNext.src=settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage+1][0]}if(settings.activeImage>0){objPrev=new Image();objPrev.src=settings.imageArray[settings.activeImage-1][0]}}function _finish(){$('#jquery-lightbox').remove();$('#jquery-overlay').fadeOut(function(){$('#jquery-overlay').remove()});$('embed, object, select').css({'visibility':'visible'})}function ___getPageSize(){var xScroll,yScroll;if(window.innerHeight&&window.scrollMaxY){xScroll=window.innerWidth+window.scrollMaxX;yScroll=window.innerHeight+window.scrollMaxY}else if(document.body.scrollHeight>document.body.offsetHeight){xScroll=document.body.scrollWidth;yScroll=document.body.scrollHeight}else{xScroll=document.body.offsetWidth;yScroll=document.body.offsetHeight}var windowWidth,windowHeight;if(self.innerHeight){if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){windowWidth=document.documentElement.clientWidth}else{windowWidth=self.innerWidth}windowHeight=self.innerHeight}else if(document.documentElement&&document.documentElement.clientHeight){windowWidth=document.documentElement.clientWidth;windowHeight=document.documentElement.clientHeight}else if(document.body){windowWidth=document.body.clientWidth;windowHeight=document.body.clientHeight}if(yScroll<windowHeight){pageHeight=windowHeight}else{pageHeight=yScroll}if(xScroll<windowWidth){pageWidth=xScroll}else{pageWidth=windowWidth}arrayPageSize=new Array(pageWidth,pageHeight,windowWidth,windowHeight);return arrayPageSize};function ___getPageScroll(){var xScroll,yScroll;if(self.pageYOffset){yScroll=self.pageYOffset;xScroll=self.pageXOffset}else if(document.documentElement&&document.documentElement.scrollTop){yScroll=document.documentElement.scrollTop;xScroll=document.documentElement.scrollLeft}else if(document.body){yScroll=document.body.scrollTop;xScroll=document.body.scrollLeft}arrayPageScroll=new Array(xScroll,yScroll);return arrayPageScroll};function ___pause(ms){var date=new Date();curDate=null;do{var curDate=new Date()}while(curDate-date<ms)};return this.unbind('click').click(_initialize)}})(jQuery);
```

if anybody had already this problem or know how to fix this the help will be appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the jquery.lightbox-0.5.js file by Leandro Vieira Pinho. What this modified javascript file does is, it will check each image and if the width or height exceeds the screen (viewport area), then the image is resized while preserving the aspect ratio.

To use this file, you just have to copy and paste entire contents of this javascript file in your already existing jquery.lightbox-0.5.js file or you just have to replace the old file with this.

I have given 2 links: First one will let you down load the entire javascript file and the second will display the source code which you can copy and paste into your existing jquery.lightbox-0.5.js.

Download javascript file: http://turboupload.com/081zwttawcb6

Source code : http://www.sourcepod.com/twhbtf88-5047

Comment: You know that copy/paste of the same answer to try and improve your rep is frowned upon here, right? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414314)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use css:

```
#lightbox-container-image-box {
  max-width:970px; // Or your max-width
}

#lightbox-container-image img {
 max-width:950px; // (your max width - 20)
}
```

this has a slight issue on the current release of lightbox, the grey background doesn't get all the way down the page - but there is a lot that can be done here with just css.  I'd recommend against modifying the codebase of lightbox - breaks forward-compatibility.